# What is the difference between Completion time and response time when dealing with scheduling policies

Tags: operating-system, execution-time, response-time, completion, resource-scheduling

I've been looking online for a while now, trying to find definitions and examples on these two terms but I cannot seem to get a straight answer and I am simply getting more confused.

Could someone explain the difference to me.  A nice and descriptive article would help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I haven't found any link containing the description of "Completion time", nor I read that in my OS course. I think you are inquiring about the Turnaround time.

**Turnaround time** - Time required for a particular process to complete, from submission time to completion. It is equal to the sum total of *Waiting time* and *Execution time*.

**Response time** - The time taken in a program from the issuance of a command to the commence of a response to that command.(i.e.,  the time-interval between submission of a request, and the first response to that request, ***not the output*** .)

Comment: Those this mean that **Response time is the difference between first execution time and Arrival time.** according to @sudipSarker?

Comment: @jayB - I didn't get whether you're asking a question, or making a point here! Would you clarify please?

Comment: not to worry much. Asked for clarity if sudipSarker's answer was same as yours. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @jayB - Yes, just the wording difference!

Comment: Completion time is the point in time when the process terminates or finishes execution.

Answer (score 4):

**Completion Time**
Completion time Can be found from *Gantt* Chart When a process stop executing That is completion time.

**Response Time**
Response time is the difference between first execution time and Arrival time.

Answer (score 1):

In case of scheduling policies:

- COMPLETION TIME

  The time when a job or process is completed.
- RESPONSE TIME

  Time interval between the submission of a job, process or sub-
  request (the moment it enters a ready state/arrives to the scheduler) and the first response received from it.

Answer (score 1):

Completion time : this is the time when process arrives the cpu means arrival time and  + cpu execution time +any other interrupt time till the complete execution of the process. Arrival time is not added if process arrives before the execution of earlier process. 
Response time : it is the time when process gets cpu response for first time after arriving the queue. Same as waiting time.

Answer (score 0):

The time taken by the system to respond to an input and display of required updated information is termed as the response time.

The time taken from submission of the job to the time completion of the job is TurnAround Time. Sum of Burst time and the waiting Time

Answer (score -2):

**Response Time:** Time between job’s arrival in the ready queue and job’s 
completion
for example 
   - Time to echo a keystroke in editor
   - Time to compile a program

Response Time = Waiting Time + COMPLETION TIME Time

**COMPLETION TIME:** The time when a job or process is completed.

Comment: The accepted answer has given the right definition of Response Time